# Is it possible to use any virtualization technique with the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, virtualization

The Raspberry Pi computers have not much CPU power and main memory but they could be the perfect platform for virtualization exercises at university classes.

Now I'm looking for working virtualization solutions.

The [XEN project](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_ARM_with_Virtualization_Extensions) has implemented a solution to run XEN on ARM v7-A and ARM v8-A architectures.

- The Raspberry Pi 1 cannot be used with XEN because it implements the ARMv6.
- [This thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/xen/users/369667) suggests that the Raspberry Pi 2 also cannot be used with XEN. [Other sources](http://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/02/25/enabling-hyp-mode-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/) say it sould be possible.
- The Raspberry Pi 3 has an ARM Cortex-A53 processor and according to the [XEN project](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_ARM_with_Virtualization_Extensions) it is supported by XEN. Did anybody test XEN with the Raspberry Pi 3?

Another hypervisor solution that [should work](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45081) on the Raspberry Pi is the type-1-hypervisor [Xvisor](http://xhypervisor.org/).

[Some](http://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/) [tutorials](https://blog.night-shade.org.uk/2015/05/kvm-on-the-raspberry-pi2/) explain using the type-2-hypervisor KVM on the Raspberry Pi 2 but it is obviously not trivial to get KVM running.

Do any further solutions exist to implement virtualization with the Raspberry Pi 2 or 3?

**Update 1**

Some tutorials exist which explain the installation and usage of Linux Containers (LXC) with the Raspberry Pi. LXC is also a virtualization technique, but not a type-1- or type-2-hypervisor (see [here](https://raspberrypicloud.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/building-an-lxc-friendly-kernel-for-the-raspberry-pi/) and [here](https://raspberrypicloud.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/creating-an-lxc-container-on-the-raspberry-pi/)). Up to now the best tutorial I found is [this](https://schtobia.de/lxc-on-raspberry-pi-de.html) one, which is in german language.

Comment: I think it's still too early to know exactly. Just dropping my two cents here.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://resin.io/blog/building-arm-containers-on-any-x86-machine-even-dockerhub/

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what performance is acceptable, plain [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) without KVM may be a viable solution. Assuming you need to run x86 system installed in `disk.img`,

```
apt-get install qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-i386 -hda disk.img
```

This is enough to run old stuff (DOS, Windows 95 and their equivalents from the nineteens in other architectures).

Another virtualization solution is [Exagear](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/exagear-desktop-review-virtualisation-on-pi/) which can run demanding stuff like Skype, but it's commercial software and limited to Linux targets and x86.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an answer for people like me: I was looking to run a couple of services on my raspberry pi.

The **only** two working solutions I found are:

1. Running the HypriosOS which is a Raspbian with Docker included. [link](http://blog.hypriot.com/downloads/)
2. For full VM capabilities, I tried and tried running LXC and LXD linux containers on Raspbian, Ubuntu Mate and what not, but all tutorials included compiling kernels with non-existent switches. I found a seamless experience with Arch. [Install Arch linux on the PI](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) and then run `pacman -S lxc`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that VMware are working on a bare-metal hypervisor (ESXi) for 64-bit Arm processors, as they have showed off on their VMworld US shindig in Las Vegas (August 2018).

It seems that soon we will be able to cluster multiple Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ (arm64), into a normal working virtualization solutions as wee see today with x86.

[Reference](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/08/27/vmware_esxi_arm64/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Minos, v0.2.1 has support Raspberry Pi 3.

https://github.com/minosproject/minos

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to test this out, but haven't done it myself. I saw this guy's article explaining how to install OpenStack on Rpi. 
(http://openstack.prov12n.com/openstack-on-raspberry-pi-part-1-why/)

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, what happens if the link breaks in the future?

Comment: The tutorial is incomplete. The author created three parts ([1](http://openstack.prov12n.com/openstack-on-raspberry-pi-part-1-why/), [2](http://openstack.prov12n.com/openstack-on-raspberry-pi-part-2-getting-started/) and [3](http://openstack.prov12n.com/openstack-on-raspberry-pi-part-3-packages/)). BTW: The tutorial uses Linux Containers (LXC) which is also a virtualization technique, but not a type-1- or type-2-hypervisor (see [here](https://raspberrypicloud.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/creating-an-lxc-container-on-the-raspberry-pi/)).

Comment: We're [trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538). If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.